# How to accelerate python script and reduce memory consumption?

Tags: python, performance, compilation

I have a python script which is uses numpy, sklearn and a lot of other stuff. This script should analyse in online thousands wav-files of 500kb size. And when I run in parallel mode this script python consume almost all memory.

I am wondering if it is possible, for example, 'compile' python script or do something to make it cheaper to run script in parallel.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as *compile* in python, even though there is a compilation happening implicitly but it has nothing to do with this problem. You are probably running out of memory because you are not controlling the number of parallel processes/threads in your application.

You can create a pool and then work with it to have some degree of control on resource consumption.
from multiprocessing import Pool

```
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

You can look at this link for more details 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html

Keep your pool size equal to the number of cores in your processor for optimal performance.